# Refresh main view after close a mondal (with click on button or outside)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i have a modal and after do a ajax-formular job i want that the mainpage (view) will refresh/reload.

How i can do that?

Comment: On ajax success reload the page.

Comment: That depends on your logic. There is no information at all provided in the question except what you wish to achieve. People will not be able to give you a specific answer, but only broad answers, which won't help you much with the general understanding that's underlining in your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to fit those guidelines. Help us help you.

Comment: on sucess the content of the modal will be updated -  thats important to see for the user. Only after he close the modal the page should be refresh. if i do it in your way, the modal is close without the last content after refresh

Comment: Then trigger a page refresh on modal close. There is plenty in the docs to do this. Make an effort, and if after doing so you still have problems update your question with what you have trried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the easy way to do it

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 location.reload(); //or what you want to do
})
```